# Arranging numbers according to distance

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

**Problem:** We have the multiset $\{ 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, \cdots \text{n}, \text{n} \}$. Using all the elements of the multiset exactly once, we need to arrange them as a 2n+1 length sequence such that between two occurences of the same number k there are k-1 numbers in between and 0 is in the centre of the array. For which n can such a sequence be constructed?

**My attempt** It is clear that no such arrangement exists for $n= 1, 2$. I am able to construct such arrays for $n= 3, 4$. For instance for 4 we have $2, 4, 2, 3, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1$. I have also through casework and symmetry shown that no such arrangement is possible for $n=5$. However, I am not able to proceed.

Any hints or answers are welcome.

Comment: hint: imagine slots numbered from 1 to $2n+1$. Number $i$ occupy slot $a_{i}$ and $a_{i}+i$. Try checking for parity

Comment: Hello! using parity, I am able to conclude that n is either 4k or 4k+3 form. How to proceed from here?

Comment: How can you construct $n=1, 2$ if the number $0$ must be in the center?

Comment: @antkam yes you are correct, I will edit.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Hello! using parity, I am able to conclude that n is either 4k or 4k+3 form. How to proceed from here?